# Setting the Maximum size of a JFrame while launching the application

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to set the Maximum size of the JFrame while launching the application.
Problem is, if the screen resolution is more my frame is getting bigger , but at that time it should not cross the max range defined, but same case works fine with low resolution.

Like I want my frame to be of Maximum of (500,500) , so I wrote this piece of code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FRAME TRANSPARENT");
frame.setSize((int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()-50), (int)(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()-150));
frame.setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(0,0 , 500, 500)); 
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Even I set the Bound, the JFrame is considering setSize method and it seems to be that it is neglecting the setMaximizedBounds method.
I already tried with setMaximumized method but got the same output.

Comment: Why `setMaximizedBounds` instead of `setMaximumSize`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried it and you're so right that `setMaximumSize()` doesn't work.. all these years couldn't get to know that!!! Mostly my requirements of limiting size is fixed by `setResizable(false)`, although I see you have specific query of minimum and maximum sizes to be different

Worked on a solution for you though:

```
public class MaxSizeUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MaxSizeUI().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Fram") {

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Dimension d = getSize();
                Dimension m = getMaximumSize();
                boolean resize = d.width > m.width || d.height > m.height;
                d.width = Math.min(m.width, d.width);
                d.height = Math.min(m.height, d.height);
                if (resize) {
                    Point p = getLocation();
                    setVisible(false);
                    setSize(d);
                    setLocation(p);
                    setVisible(true);
                }
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes your frame flicker on the screen as it reaches the max width or height. In some cases, it gets into an infinite loop hiding itself and reshowing.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solutions is:

```
Dimension DimMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setMaximumSize(DimMax);

frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score -2):

use dimension 
`Dimension d=getMaximumSize(); Frame.setSize(d.width, d.height);`